# E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: INVALID_SENDER when not using firebase in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Hi I'm a beginner with Android Studio so just looking for some help. I created an app and everything worked fine. I tried to replace a new version with an older version of my app by pasting it in from another folder. The emulator will now not run the app and gives the error:

E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: INVALID_SENDER

My app uses PHP my admin for the login I have not done anything with firebase so I'm confused as to what has went wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using Firebase anywhere? It does a lot more than just logging in, crash reporting is a common use case.

Comment: No I'm not certain, I don't recall using it for anything. I just know the project worked until I copied it to a new location and now I'm getting this issue.

Comment: Alright, I think you need to search your project for Firebase and figure out if / how it's being used. You can then follow their setup guides to make sure you've got your `google-services.json` file in the right place. Before that though, you could try cleaning & rebuilding the project.